# websocket receiving incomplette data

Tags: django, django-channels

receiving data from websocket i have notice that fields are missing from the models

> please help you can see the resualt in postman wil connecting to the django channels

**consumer.py**

```
 # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        method = event['method']
        model = event['model']
        data = event['data']
        description = event['description']
        receiver = event['receiver']
        sender = event['sender']
        created = event['created']
        seen = event['seen']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'method': method,
            'model': model,
            'data': data,
            'description': description,
            'receiver': receiver,
            'sender': sender,
            'created': created,
            'seen': seen,
        }))
```

**views.py**

```
async_to_sync(layer.group_send)(("chat_" + str(channel_name)), {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'method': 'POST',
                'model': 'social',
                'data': json.dumps(serializers.data),
                'description': 'new post',
                'sender': json.dumps(LikeSerializer(request.user, many=False).data),
                'receiver': json.dumps(sorted(my_profile.profile_followers.all().values_list('id', flat=True))),
                'created': json.dumps(str(timezone.now())),
                'seen': None
            })
```

**resualt**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1QgP.png)